# What would it mean to have equal canonical coefficients (A,B) as a result of CCA?

Tags: canonical-correlation

I am using CCA to compare two  matrices of n by m dimensions.

---

```
    [A,B,r,U,V,stats] = canoncorr(Xtrain,Ytrain);   % Mean Centered Xtrain,Ytrain
                Vpred = (Yheld) * B;                % Mean Centered Yheld
                V_manipulated = Vpred / A;

compare Accuracy of  (Yheld, V_manipulated)
```

1. `Vpred/A` is only possible because `(Xtrain,Ytrain)` have the dame dimentions , thus A, B are square Matrices.
2. If: $$A = B => (Yheld) * B * A^{-1} = Yheld = > V_manipulated = Yheld$$
3. What would that mean for `(Xtrain,Ytrain)`?
4. Us there any way to compare the similarity of `(Xtrain,Ytrain)`?